# How to configure asp.net webforms WebMethod Date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, date-format, webmethod

I have a webmethod that receives an object that contains a date property.
I am passing a json that represents the object to the webmethod.
asp.net automatically converts the json string to an object so my method looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Object Save(MyObject item)
{
   ....
}

public class MyObject 
{
     DateTime date;
     .....
}
```

This all works well when the date is sent in USA format: `'MM/dd/yyyy'`
When the date is sent in European format: `'dd/MM/yyy'` I receive an error.

I am setting the culture of the thread in global asax:

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var s = GetSessionValues();
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(s.CultureID);
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(s.CultureID);
}
```

This code runs correctly it reads the culture id from the session and sets it.
The culture id is read into the session upon login from the database.

But this seems to have no affect on the date format expected by the web method i receive the error:

```
"31/08/2012 is not a valid value for DateTime.",
"StackTrace":"  
at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AssignToPropertyOrField(Object propertyValue, Object o, String memberName, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n  
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException"}
```

How can I set the expected date format for the webmethod (I have a lot of these web method so obviously I want a solution that would apply for all of them).

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a webmethod that receives an object that contains a date property. I am passing a json that represents the object to the webmethod. asp.net automatically converts the json string to an object

Given that you're accepting JSON, this should *not* be culture-sensitive IMO. Convert all data into (including numbers and dates/times) into a culture-insensitive format at the client side.

So if you're accepting date input in a UI, get the JavaScript to convert that into a date/time object locally, and then convert that into whatever specific format you want to use. (Personally I'd suggest using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` as a nicely unambiguous format, but there we go.)

Think of JSON as a machine-readable serialization format which *happens* to be easy to read for humans too. Keeping all the culture-specific parsing at the client-side will make your life much simpler.

EDIT: Fundamentally, you need to work out what your value in JSON means. If it's text for human consumption, then treat it as a string, don't try to parse it, and produce it in whatever culture you want to be displayed. If it's a date/time value for *machine* consumption, then treat it that way and product it in a culture-neutral way (fixed format, invariant culture). Trying to treat the value as a mixture of human-readable and machine-readable *will* give you problems like this.

Comment: I read the date from a text box (with a date-picker) and I have generic client side code that reads dates/number etc. as text.
The date is displayed according to the users culture as saved in the DB so I would like to be able to configure the Date Format for the method that deserializes the json. Is this possible? if it is impossible I suppose I will have to do as you say and then the client side will have to know what the users culture is in order to transfer text to date and back to text again. I would rather not do it this way.

Comment: @Daniel: You should definitely do it client side. Ideally, you shouldn't be reading as text from the date-picker to start with - it should provide you with a `Date` or something similar. You can then convert it to text in a culture-insensitive way. This is likely to be *far* less problematic than trying to deal with the a culture-sensitive format on the server.

Comment: Is there no global way of telling webmethods what date format to use? why should this be difficult? I have ~20 or so pages doing this, they do use global js code so it shouldn't be a big problem to do this but it seems to me server side is the right place to do this keeping the client side as dumb as possible.

Comment: p.s. the culture is not dependent on the browser it depends on the user settings in the DB so the server already handles culture. i would like for it to handle all the culture issues.

Comment: @Daniel: That makes no sense to me - you've talked about the JSON coming from the client... is that not what's deciding what to use? You shouldn't be passing *text* into the database at all. You should be passing in `DateTime` values. It sounds like you need to clarify your question significantly. I don't know of any global way of telling `WebMethods` what date format to use, but it shouldn't be too hard to simply use the same one everywhere, using a constant value so you'd only have one place to change.

Comment: @Daniel: But "i would like for it to handle all the culture issues" is simply not a good idea, IMO. JSON is a machine-to-machine serialization format - why would you *want* culture-sensitive formats in it? It may seem further away from where you are now, but really - your life will be *much* simpler if you can isolate the culture issues of your input at the client.

Comment: The date is pulled from a text box which is written into by client code that reads from a JSON that comes from the server. the client does not know if it is a date a number or just text. I do not pass text to the DB the json is automatically de-serialized (I do not do the de-serializing manually) into objects. If there is no way to configure the json deserializer i will have to do it on the client but I think there should be a way of doing this. what SHOULD be done  should be left for the developer to decide in a specific situation.

Comment: @Daniel: Okay, it sounds like you *really* need to give more details in the question. It's very unclear what this application is, what the client is etc. If your JSON values are *just* meant to be culture-specific text, then that's one thing - but you shouldn't try to deserialize them as if they were `DateTime` values. Basically you need to decide whether you're using JSON to move *strings* from one place to another, or *values* (numbers, dates and times etc). Values should be machine-readable and culture-insensitive; strings should be human-readable; don't try to parse them.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the parameter type to string and then you can convert that string to any type you want

```
public void Save(MyObject itemdate){
    *Code*
}
public class MyObject 
{
     string date;
     .....
}
```

ie:

```
DateTime myEurpeonDate= DateTime.ParseExact(MyObject.date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `culture` and `uiCulture` to `en-GB` in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
<system.web>
```

Comment: I need the culture to be dynamic as i specified. it is loaded from the session (which is loaded from database upon login).

Answer (score 0):

Call either the **TryParse** or the **Parse** method of the **DateTime** or **DateTimeOffset** type to try the conversion. Also use **CultureInfo** object in it. A good example given below..

- [Display Localized Date and Time Information to Web Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882561.aspx)

Also may be helpful..

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)